# linux cron script with function doesn't running

Tags: linux, bash, cron, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to run a script as a job in the cron.

The script:

```
echo "Defining function"
function talkMe() {
        echo "me"
}
echo "Start talking"
talkMe
```

The cron job:

```
0 18 * * * /scripts/talk.sh > /tmp/talk.log
```

The cron errror:

```
Aug 23 11:24:01 database CRON[8497]: (root) CMD (/scripts/talk.sh > /tmp/talk.log)
Aug 23 11:24:01 database CRON[8494]: (CRON) error (grandchild #8497 failed with exit status 2)
```

The test.log:

```
Defining function
```

The script was working fine BEFORE I try this to change the ROOT password:

```
sudo su
passwd <my new pass for root>
```

This command seems to have no effect and the ROOT continues with the old password... but  after this commands the CRON problems appeared!

How can I solve the CRON problem, to run the script correctly?

Note: running manually the script, everything goes fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script has no she-bang line. Insert this line to the top of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It is possible that the script is being run by a different shell that uses a different syntax to define functions.

Answer (score 2):

Try following one. also check in /var/log/cron logs

```
0 18 * * * /bin/bash /scripts/talk.sh > /tmp/talk.log
```

Comment: Some its could be be PATH issue so you can add following in your crontab PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Answer (score 2):

@choroba has pointed out the major problem: your script has no shebang, so you have no idea what shell it's run in. The secondary problem is that `function` is nonstandard -- bash tolerates (i.e. ignores) it, but some other shells will barf on it:

```
$ function talkMe() {
sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
$ echo $?
2
```

(Note that the exit status here matches what's in the log.)

Fixing either problem should be enough to make it work, but it's probably best to fix both:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Defining function"
talkMe() {
    echo "me"
}
echo "Start talking"
talkMe
```